# how to pass xkeyval cmdkey to macro

Tags: expansion, xkeyval

I want to pass a `cmdkey` from the `xkeyval` package to a macro. I can print the value of the `cmdkey` to a message, but when used with `\in@` it seems to be unexpanded.  Example below. I expect to see the messages

```
the value is aaacde. the action is true.
```

Instead I only see `the value is aaacde`. When I use a string for the comparison it does work (see commented out line).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\newif\ifaction
\makeatletter
\define@cmdkeys{links}[link@]{book,chap}{}
\setkeys{links}{book=aaacde, chap=asdf}
\def\testme{%
    \message{the value  is \link@book.}
    \in@{aaa}{\link@book}% does not work
    %\in@{aaa}{aaabcd}% works
    \ifin@\actiontrue\message{the action is true.}\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

text\testme

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand `\link@book` before `\in@` does its thing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\newif\ifaction
\makeatletter
\define@cmdkeys{links}[link@]{book,chap}{}
\setkeys{links}{book=aaacde, chap=asdf}
\def\reversed@in@#1#2{\in@{#2}{#1}}% <-- Added this
\def\testme{%
    \message{the value  is \link@book.}
    \expandafter\reversed@in@\expandafter{\link@book}{aaa}% <-- Changed here
    %\in@{aaa}{aaabcd}% works
    \ifin@\actiontrue\message{the action is true.}\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

text\testme

\end{document}
```

I added a `\reversed@in@` macro so that we can expand the first argument instead of the second. As a rule of thumb, the latter the argument is, the harder it is to expand it (not *always* true, though). Thus I used the `\reversed@in@` macro to swap the arguments to `\in@`.

Comment: I get ! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \reversed@in@
I'm using pdflatex.

Comment: @TimA I think you forgot to copy the definition of `\reversed@in@` I added. I clarified this in the answer.

Comment: thanks for that pointer, you're right I didn't see that definition. So you did that to make the expandafter work, because otherwise it couldn't be done, right?

Comment: @TimA I did that to simplify the code. As I said, later arguments _can_ be expanded, but it gets trickier. You could, instead of the `\reversed@in@` thing, replace `\in@{aaa}{\link@book}` by `\edef\@tempa{\noexpand\in@{\unexpanded{aaa}}{\expandafter\noexpand\link@book}}\@tempa`. It would also expand `\link@book` once. Or, if `\expandafter`s are your thing, you could use `\def\aaa{aaa}\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\in@\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\aaa\expandafter}\expandafter{\link@book}` :-)

Comment: @TimA Side note: this argument swapping is more or less how `expl3` controls argument expansion.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I think I'll stick with \reversed@in@ !

Answer (score 1):

You can define `\expandedin@`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\newif\ifaction

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\expandedin@}[2]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\in@{#1}{#2}}\x
}

\define@cmdkeys{links}[link@]{book,chap}{}
\def\testme{%
    \message{the value is \link@book.}%
    \expandedin@{aaa}{\link@book}%
    \ifin@\actiontrue\message{the action is true.}\fi
}
\makeatother

\setkeys{links}{book=aaacde, chap=asdf}

\begin{document}

text\testme

\end{document}
```

With a newer version of the engines (available with TeX Live 2019), you can use `\expanded`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval}

\newif\ifaction

\makeatletter
\define@cmdkeys{links}[link@]{book,chap}{}
\def\testme{%
    \message{the value is \link@book.}%
    \expanded{\noexpand\in@{aaa}{\link@book}}% 
    \ifin@\actiontrue\message{the action is true.}\fi
}
\makeatother

\setkeys{links}{book=aaacde, chap=asdf}

\begin{document}

text\testme

\end{document}
```

Comment: wow, that makes it worth installing the 2019 distro, so simple. In your first example, can you explain the begingroup--endgroup pair? I think I understand the rest. What happens if I left them out? \edef\x{\noexpand\in@{#1}{#2}}\x (I don't see a difference in the result).

Comment: @TimA That's for avoiding to leave a definition of `\x`: after `\x` is expanded, TeX finds `\endgroup`, which removes the (re)definition of `\x`, but the resulting token list is already there.